# Hide a DIV when HTML Lang is detected

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, lang

I need to hide a DIV section when certain HTML Lang is detected, but here are so many language options, so I am thinking on a simple way to show this DIV **only** if Lang is equal to EN (in all its country possibilities, such as EN-en, EN-us, EN-au, etc.), other languages will keep this DIV on *display:none;*
But I can't figure out how can I do this via CSS only, I just wonder if someone has tried this before.
Also, I am open to other possibilities to make it work.
Thank you!

Comment: highly doubt it will be CSS only

Comment: Which method do you recommend?

Comment: If you're talking about a `lang` attribute on the `html` element, you can do it in CSS. If you're talking about something else, calling it "HTML Lang" is somewhat misleading.

Comment: `html:not([lang=^"en"])  #myDiv{display:none";}` is probably what you look for. .. or the  opposite if i misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a little bit of JavaScript and CSS by appending [navigator.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) to your body's class via [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```js
document.body.classList.add(navigator.language)
```

and then style your div

```css
body div.someClass {display: none}
body[class*="en-"] div.someClass {display: block}
```

Answer (score 2):

from my comment :

> `html:not([lang=^"en"])  #myDiv{display:none";}` is probably what you look for. .. or the opposite if i misunderstood.

here an example with `lang` inside a `div` (we cannot set 2 `html` tag side by side)

```css
div:not([lang^="EN"]) .myDiv {
  display: none;
}

[lang^="EN"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div lang="EN-en">
  test 1
  <div class="myDiv"> show if html lang is english</div>
</div>
<div lang="EN-us">
  test 2
  <div class="myDiv"> show if html lang is english</div>
</div>
<div lang="EN-au">
  test 3
  <div class="myDiv"> show if html lang is english</div>
</div>
<div lang="fr">
  test 4
  <div class="myDiv"> show if html lang is english</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add css like this...

```
.demo {
   display: block;
}
html[lang="en"] .demo {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Use a "contains" selector for better matching (i.e., `html[lang*="en"]`)